# Error #1349: View's select cluse contains a subquery in the from clause

Tags: sql, querying

Here is my code:

```
SELECT CAST.first_name,
  CAST.last_name,
  AWARDED.castID,
  COUNT(*) AwardsWon
FROM AWARDED,
  ROLE,
  CAST
WHERE ROLE.role    = "Director"
AND ROLE.castID    = AWARDED.castID
AND ROLE.movieID   = AWARDED.movieID
AND AWARDED.castID = CAST.castID
GROUP BY castID
HAVING COUNT(*) =
  (SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM AWARDED GROUP BY CastID
    ) z
  )
```

When I try and create a view from this code I get an error of the form: #1349 view's select contains a subquery in the from clause. Are there any ways that this can be worked around?

Answer (score 0):

The statement says...

•   The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.

Your workaround would be to create a view for each of your subqueries.

Then access those views from within your view

Comment: Not sure how that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you are using MySQL. Not sure but your said query can be transformed as below. give it a try.

```
SELECT `CAST`.first_name,
  `CAST`.last_name,
  AWARDED.castID,
  COUNT(AWARDED.castID) AwardsWon
FROM AWARDED
JOIN ROLE
ON ROLE.movieID = AWARDED.movieID
AND ROLE.castID = AWARDED.castID
JOIN `CAST`
ON AWARDED.castID = `CAST`.castID
WHERE ROLE.role = 'Director'
GROUP BY AWARDED.castID,`CAST`.first_name,`CAST`.last_name
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(AwardsWon);
```